# Error parsing xml returned results from api url call with php

Tags: php, simplexml

what I am missing here? all I get returned is "Location: 0"

```
ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");

$url = "http://ebird.org/ws1.1/data/notable/region/recent?rtype=subnational1&r=US-AZ";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$locname = $xml->response->result->sighting->loc-id;

echo "Location: ".$locname . "<br/>";
```

Comment: `loc-id` is probably a typo. Do you mean `loc->id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the probelem is with the "-" because php think that you want to subtract `id` from `$xml->response->result->sighting->loc`

the solution is to change :

```
$locname = $xml->response->result->sighting->loc-id;
```

to

```
$locname = $xml->result[0]->sighting[0]->{'loc-id'};
```

it work with me

i hope this help you

note :  i delete `response` node because it's the root and i choose the first elemet because the file containe many nodes

Comment: thank you so much. i knew it was something simple, just looked at it for way too long.